# In Flux language, how can I remove table from table stream according to table characteristics, rather than row characteristics?

Tags: influxdb, flux-influxdb

I know how to use filter function in flux to filter-out rows. Is it possible to filter-out tables from table steam.

For example:

```
from(bucket: "bucket")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._field == "price")  // filter rows, not tables
|> filter(fn: (table) => table._value is a constant)  // is this possible?
```

Is there a way to do this in flux?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Tables represents series. You need to filter out specific series  ie. combination of tag values and `_measurement` to remove corresponding tables from output.